# Magento: Dropdown menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, magento-1.9

I'm working on Magento based website. With my limited knowledge of Magento and php, I'm having hard time to figure this matter. Hope someone can help me. 
I'm working on dropdown menu. For example I have currently 4 categories look like HOME | FASHION | SPORT | BEAUTY 
I like to do look like this HOME | PRODUCT. And in the PRODUCT category there fashion, sport and beauty categories. 
How can i do this? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Home is a Category itself, in the admin panel: Catalog->Categories->Manage
Create a 'Product' Category Under Home then drag and drop Fashion, Sport, and Beauty into Product.

Reindex, clear cache, and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to to go to Catalog->Manage Categories.
On the left panel under categories , You simply need to click on the Home category and click on Add Subcategory (Product). After creating the Product sub category you can drag all your categories to it.